# yii2, how to change structure from controller/view?id= to controller/view/username

Tags: yii2

how can i change structure URL from

`http://localhost:8888/traitor/?id=24`

to

`http://localhost:8888/traitor/JohnRichmond` (FirstName + LastName)

Comment: You can edit your url rules to get desired results, and links who has the id as query parameter

Answer (score 0):

configure the `urlManager` component in the application configuration like the following: `web.php`

```
[
    'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules' => [
               'traitor/<name:[A-Za-z]+>' => 'traitor/action',
                // ...
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

**URL from:**

```
 http://localhost:8888/traitor/?name=JohnRichmond
```

**To:**

```
 http://localhost:8888/traitor/JohnRichmond
```

You must configure as above.
Then, if you need queryStrings(FirstName & LastName), separate them with php. Example:

```
$str= 'JohnRichmond';
$array = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', $str);
```

In my opinion the following is better:

**URL from:**

```
 http://localhost:8888/traitor/?first=John&last=Richmond
```

**To:**

```
 http://localhost:8888/traitor/John/Richmond

        'rules' => [
           'traitor/<first:[A-Za-z]+>/<last:[A-Za-z]+>' => 'traitor/action',
            // 'traitor/<first:\w+>/<last:\w+>' => 'traitor/action', // \w+: [a-zA-Z0-9_]

        ],
```

**check:**

```
       Url::toRoute(['traitor', 'first' => 'John', 'last' => 'Richmond'])
```

Good luck.